# Converting thrust::iterators to and from raw pointers

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to use Thrust library to calculate prefix sum of device array in CUDA.
My array is allocated with `cudaMalloc()`. My requirement is as follows:

```
main()  
{  
     Launch kernel 1 on data allocated through cudaMalloc()  
     // This kernel will poplulate some data d.  
     Use thrust to calculate prefix sum of d.  
     Launch kernel 2 on prefix sum.  
}
```

I want to use Thrust somewhere between my kernels so I need method to convert pointers to device iterators and back.What is wrong in following code?

```
int main()                                                        
{                                                                 
    int *a;                                                   
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a,N*sizeof(int));   
    thrust::device_ptr<int> d=thrust::device_pointer_cast(a);  
    thrust::device_vector<int> v(N);                    
    thrust::exclusive_scan(a,a+N,v);                          
    return 0;                                                  
}
```

Comment: Is this edit intended to ask a new question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A complete working example from your latest edit would look like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()                                                        
{                                                                 
    const int N = 16;
    int * a;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a, N*sizeof(int));   
    thrust::device_ptr<int> d = thrust::device_pointer_cast(a);  
    thrust::fill(d, d+N, 2);
    thrust::device_vector<int> v(N);                    
    thrust::exclusive_scan(d, d+N, v.begin());

    int v_[N];
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), v_);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", i, v_[i]);     

    return 0;                                                  
}
```

The things you got wrong:

1. `N` not defined anywhere
2. passing the raw device pointer `a` rather than the `device_ptr` `d` as the input iterator to `exclusive_scan`
3. passing the `device_vector` `v` to `exclusive_scan` rather than the appropriate iterator `v.begin()`

Attention to detail was all that is lacking to make this work. And work it does:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_12 -o thrust_kivekset thrust_kivekset.cu 
$ ./thrust_kivekset

0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
5 10
6 12
7 14
8 16
9 18
10 20
11 22
12 24
13 26
14 28
15 30
```

---

Edit:

`thrust::device_vector.data()` will return a `thrust::device_ptr` which points to the first element of the vector. `thrust::device_ptr.get()` will return a raw device pointer. Therefore

```
cudaMemcpy(v_, v.data().get(), N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

and

```
thrust::copy(v, v+N, v_);
```

are functionally equivalent in this example.

Comment: One more thing such error pops up:thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0043f3a8..

Comment: See my edit. Having basically re-answered your already answered and accepted question *twice*, perhaps a vote might in order.

Comment: I have posted a demonstration showing the code compiling and running correctly. As I alluded to on your other question, you are getting ECC errors and other symptoms which suggest either a software installation or hardware problem.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your raw pointer obtained from `cudaMalloc()` to a `thrust::device_ptr` using `thrust::device_pointer_cast`. Here's an example from the Thrust docs:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t N = 10;

    // obtain raw pointer to device memory
    int * raw_ptr;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &raw_ptr, N * sizeof(int));

    // wrap raw pointer with a device_ptr 
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(raw_ptr);

    // use device_ptr in Thrust algorithms
    thrust::fill(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + N, (int) 0);    

    // access device memory transparently through device_ptr
    dev_ptr[0] = 1;

    // free memory
    cudaFree(raw_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Use `thrust::inclusive_scan` or `thrust::exclusive_scan` to compute the prefix sum.

http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#Prefix-Sums

Comment: I tried but doesn't work for me.. I've added source code in question please hav a look at it